# Improving Task code to achieve async await

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task

I am creating a task and then assign a thread that waits for the task to be completed and then modify the UI.

```
 string txt = txtHelloMessage.Text;
 HelloTask = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                string msg = client.SayHello(txt);
                return msg;
            }
            );
 new Thread(
           () =>
            {
                while (true)// waiting for completion, I think that this is wrong
                {
                    if (HelloTask.IsCompleted)
                    {
                        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate() { txtHelloMessage.Text = HelloTask.Result; });
                        break;

                    }
                }

            }
            ).Start();
```

Is this good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not good practice.

You're using a very heavy and expensive Thread to handle the outcome of a lightweight (cheap) Task.

In this case you could just let the Task itself do the Invoke(), or use a continuation.

But the code looks very artificial, maybe post something closer to your real problem.

Comment: Yes, it is just a sample.I am looking for a better practice to the second part mainly (waiting for the result)

Comment: Wait for the result or process the result?

Comment: waiting for the result and then process( while(true){..}) this part

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using .NET 4.5 / C# 5, you could use the `await` keyword. Here's a really stupid, simple example:

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await GetSomeTextForSomeReason();
    }

    private async Task GetSomeTextForSomeReason()
    {
        var s = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                  {
                                      for (int i = 0; i < 500000000; i++) ; // simulate a delay
                                      return "This is text";
                                  });
        textBox1.Text = s;
    }
```

Comment: I am using C# 4.5 and not .Net 4.5

Comment: @sleimanjneidi There is no C# 4.5. The latest release version of C# is 4.0. C# 5.0 will be released with Visual Studio 11.